# How to delete database row if the success = 2 message appears?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dom

UPDATE:

Right this is what I want for the solution. When the user clicks on the "Cancel" button, it would try to find the file name of the file that is going to be cancelled and then delete the database row containing that file name.

The problem is that it is not recognizing the file name as it is stating that `imagecancelname=undefined`. As this is undefined, it can't delete the database row containing the file name as it doesn't recognise the name of the file.

So the question is that how can I get `imagecancelname` to recognise the name of the file which is going to be cancelled so then it can be used to be able to delete the database row containing the file name?

Below is the current form code:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
  "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
  "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +     
  "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'></p>" +
  "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is the startImageUpload function where it displays the cancel button when file is uploading and where it contains the cancel button function if the user clicks on the Cancel button:

```
function startImageUpload(imagecancelname){

        $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).html('<div><button type="button" class="imageCancel" image_cancel="' + imagecancelname + '">Cancel</button></div>'); 

            $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
                var image_cancel = $(this).attr('image_cancel');

              var url = 'cancelimage.php';
window.location=url+"?imagecancelname=" + image_cancel;

});       
      return true;
}
```

Finally below is the cancelimage.php script where when the user clicks on the Cancel button, it will navigate to this script and this is where the script is used to delete the database row by finding the file name using the $GET method.

```
    <?php

    ... connected to DB

    $image_cancel = $_GET["imagecancelname"];

            $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
            WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_cancel)."'";

        mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

        mysql_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript you could just add an additional php file to delete a row from database.

Add this in your js (when you delete):

```
window.location=url+"?"+id;
```

`url` = path where the php file is located

`id` = the row id which you would like to delete

Then add a php file to do the database operation

```
<?php
    $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
               WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/".
               mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
```

Id is a parameter which you need to pass as parameter from javascript.
For example:
If you would like to delete an image which has got an name `black`, then pass 
In Javascript:

```
var image = 'black';
window.location=url+"?id="+image;
```

Later in the php file get the value of id using:

```
$image = $_GET['id'];
```

Then execute your query:

```
$imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM IMAGE WHERE IMAGEFILE = $image";
```

Comment: Hi, just one question, If the php file (cancelimage.php) is in the same directory as the application, then is this the correct code: `var url="<?php echo \cancelimage.php;?>?action=phpFunction&vars="+var;`

Comment: Yes, you could check that by
`alert(window.location);`

Also, check if your `cancelimage.php` is getting called placing some print statements in your `cancelimage.php`

Comment: I am just struggling coding this: `window.location=url+"?"+id;`. url is cancelimage.php and I don't quite understand row id. Is this the row of the database?

Comment: @user1391585 I have just updated my answer.
Please check and let me know if you have any issue.
Glad to help

Comment: Hi, you showed if id is 'black' then it will find an image which contains black, but what happens if it could be any image. Because any image could be deleted. I have updated the question by including the code of the form showing the file input and its buttons.

Comment: its recommended to delete image based on its id and not name.
You should have an id for images stored in the database.
DELETE IMAGE FROM IMAGEFILE WHERE imageID = $id;

Comment: I am going to update question and code so you know what is happening but in short, it is not recognising the file name so it is unable to delete the database row. But please read question when updated and you will fully understand what is happening

Comment: Question is updated, please look at update question to see what is happening :)

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not recognising the file name`?

Comment: What do you mean by `it is not recognising the file name`?
Could you please print that ` $imagecancelsql` variable and just print the query and exit, so we will check if the query is printed correctly.

Comment: Also check the path where the image is stored in the database.
and just cross-check with the sql query printed.

Comment: Lets say for example I selected file "Tulips.png" and then clicked on "Upload" to upload file, but then I decide I want to cancel the upload and click on the "Cancel" button, the file is not uploaded into the server. The print $imagecancelsql should state: `DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/Tulips.png ` but instead as it is not recognizing the name of the file it is stating this: `DELETE FROM Image WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/undefined' `

Comment: I am not sure why that does not work.
Another alternative for this is using ajax:

$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : '/path/to/phpfile',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: {
 image : yourImage
 },
  success : function(data) {
alert('sucess');
  } else {
 alert('failed');
}

Comment: I tried using jquery.ajax like this: `jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?imagecancelname=" + image_cancel);` but still did not work. Is it because the file isn't stored in the server when its cancelled so it can't get the file name from there? Or could it be that because php cannot be met until upload is initialized?